# Asyncio in python3.5 spams with INFO

Tags: python, python-asyncio

When I enable asyncio debugging in Python 3.5, I get messages like this almost every second:

```
INFO:asyncio:poll 999.470 ms took 1001.159 ms: timeout
INFO:asyncio:poll 999.264 ms took 1001.092 ms: timeout
INFO:asyncio:poll 999.454 ms took 1001.059 ms: timeout
```

Here is a minimal code which reproduces this problem:

```
import asyncio
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_debug(True)

async def f(delay):
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)

loop.run_until_complete(f(0.5))
# (nothing printed)
loop.run_until_complete(f(1))
# INFO:asyncio:poll 999.470 ms took 1001.159 ms: timeout
# INFO:asyncio:poll 999.264 ms took 1001.092 ms: timeout
# INFO:asyncio:poll 999.454 ms took 1001.059 ms: timeout
# ...
loop.run_until_complete(f(2))
# INFO:asyncio:poll 1999.427 ms took 2001.112 ms: timeout
# INFO:asyncio:poll 1999.393 ms took 2001.088 ms: timeout
# INFO:asyncio:poll 1999.709 ms took 2001.758 ms: timeout
# ...
```

This doesn't print messages if `sleep` delay is lesser than 1 second, but does if it is >= 1.

Is that expected behaviour? How can I avoid such messages?

I found that problem when working with [Muffin framework](https://github.com/klen/muffin).

Comment: Seems that this problem is rooted in `aiohttp` web framework's gunicorn worker: https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/worker.py#L97 - it calls asyncio.sleep(1.0) which leads to this message when server is not busy.

Answer (score 8):

You can set logging level for asyncio module, for example:

```
logging.getLogger('asyncio').setLevel(logging.WARNING)  # Remove asyncio debug and info messages, but leave warnings.
```

BTW, [read about](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html) logging names system generally:

> The `name` is potentially a period-separated hierarchical value, like
>   `foo.bar.baz` (though it could also be just plain `foo`, for example).
>   Loggers that are further down in the hierarchical list are children of
>   loggers higher up in the list. For example, given a logger with a name
>   of `foo`, loggers with names of `foo.bar`, `foo.bar.baz`, and `foo.bam` are
>   all descendants of `foo`. The logger name hierarchy is analogous to the
>   Python package hierarchy, and identical to it if you organise your
>   loggers on a per-module basis using the recommended construction
>   `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. That’s because in a module, `__name__` is
>   the module’s name in the Python package namespace.

Answer (score 4):

> Is that expected behaviour?

Yes, see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1372

> How can I avoid such messages?

Obviously, one way is to disable logging all-together. Or you could only print `logging.DEBUG` level. Or you could write some sort of [custom filter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#filter-objects) to filter out these messages.